# Theorem on Repeating Decimals

Tags: finite-fields, decimal-expansion, cyclotomic-polynomials

So I am wondering if anyone recognizes the following theorem:

Given a prime $p$, and a base $b$ (natural number $>1$), the period of $\frac{1}{p}$ expressed in base $b$ is the unique $d$ that divides $p-1$ such that $b\mod p$ is a solution of $\Phi_d(x)\cong 0\mod p$ (where $\Phi_d(x)$ is the $d$th cyclotomic polynomial).

The reason I ask is that I proved this theorem while doing some original research a number of years back, and have been unable to find it anywhere in the literature (though this might be due to me not knowing much ring and field theory).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that $\gcd(b,p)=1$.

It is easy to show that the length $n$ of the period $d$ of $1/p$ in base $b$ is the order of $b$ in the group $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$. So $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that $p\mid b^n-1$ In this form you can probably find it in textbooks, but I cannot point you at one. I have used this as an exercise though, and I certainly didn't come up with the result myself. I just don't remember how I first heard/read about it.

Now, by the basic properties of cyclotomic polynomials we have the factorization
$$
x^n-1=\prod_{d\mid n}\Phi_d(x).
$$

Your result follows from plugging $x=b$ into this. $\Phi_d(b)$ is a factor of $b^d-1$, so the smallest $n$ such that $p\mid b^n-1$ is also the smallest $n$ such that $p\mid\Phi_n(b)$.

Comment: The nice thing about this theorem is that you can answer the following question with a finite amount of work: How does $\frac{1}{p}$ behave in _every_ base $b$?